# Refer lyx documents in a master lyx document

Tags: lyx

I have a couple of lyx documents (the children), I want to create a master document that referencing the children, but if I use Insert -> File -> Doc Lyx the file is copied inside the master document, **but** if I change the original document (a child)  **the change is not reflected in the master**.

Maybe it is not posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Insert > File > Child Document. Then click on "Browse". Then choose your LyX file. Then choose between "include" and "input".